# How can i init my single page backbone app with data from symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, backbone.js

I'm searching the solution but in vain.

I have a Symfony2 site, one page load a backbone app like this :

```
{% extends "AcmeCardBundle::layout.html.twig" %}


{% block content %}
    <div id="main_container"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script>
       var idfoo = "foo";
    </script>

    {% javascripts
    '@AcmeCardBundle/Resources/public/js/vendors/require.js'
    '@AcmeCardBundle/Resources/public/js/boot.js'%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}" data-main="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/acmecard/css/screen.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

this code load my boot.js with Requirejs

```
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost/symfony2/web/bundles/acmecard/js',
        paths: {
            jquery: 'vendors/jquery',
            underscore: 'vendors/underscore',
            backbone : 'vendors/backbone'
        }
    });

    // Start the main app logic.
    requirejs(['jquery','underscore','backbone', 'app/app','app/router' ],
        function   ( $,  _  ,  Backbone, app ) {

            $(document).ready(function () {

                console.log(window.idfoo);

                app.initialize();
            });
        }
);
```

My question is maybe stupid, but i don't understand how can i access var window.idfoo from Symfony2 in Backbone . My method don't work ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

In my twig Symfony, i put the require init like this

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
    '@AcmeCardBundle/Resources/public/js/vendors/require.js'%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}" data-main="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        requirejs.config({
            baseUrl: 'http://localhost/symfony2/web/bundles/acmecard/js',
            paths: {
                jquery: 'vendors/jquery',
                underscore: 'vendors/underscore',
                backbone : 'vendors/backbone'
            },
            config: {
                'app/app': {
                    user: '{{ app.user.username }}'
                }
            }
        });

        // Start the main app logic.
        requirejs(['jquery','underscore','backbone', 'app/app','app/router' ],
                function   ( $,  _  ,  Backbone, app ) {

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        app.initialize();
                    });
                }
        );

    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, there is a config param where you can define some var to the module ( here app/app). in this exemple i define a user.

Then in app/app.js

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {

    var initialize = function() {
        console.log(module.config().user);
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

});
```

We have to add some args and it works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not stupid at all. While I cannot help you with `backbone` itself, I had the similar problem with `AngularJS`. Nevertheless, the resolution would basically be the same.

This is how I managed to resolve it:

```
<script>
    window['myBackboneApp'] = {
        var1: 'foo',
        var2: 'bar'
    }
</script>
```

And then in your `boot.js` you reference `window['myBackboneApp']` directly.

**I am not sure if this is the right way to deal with this.** For example, only recently, I found that there is a way in `Angular` to pass attributes to controller. Maybe there is something similar for `backbone.js` as well?

Comment: This seems not working with Backbone, i'm searching a way with the requirejs.config

Comment: No it works with boot.js , no problem, but not in all loaded modules like app/app or app/router